# Android. To show clicked items text. Why does not work?

Tags: android, list, text, onclick, listener

The problem is to get what selected item contains, but I tried a lot of code and solution still not working. Somebody see the problem?

```
final List list = db.getAllClients();

    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_ID);
    listview.setClickable(true);

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listview);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String selectedText = (String) listview
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedText,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
```

stack trace :

01-15 04:37:43.058: I/Choreographer(2137): Skipped 137 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-15 04:37:44.998: I/Choreographer(2137): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

```
01-15 04:37:46.358: W/dalvikvm(2137): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aa9b90)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137): Process: com.example.assist, PID: 2137
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.assist.Client cannot be cast to java.lang.String
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at com.example.assist.ListActivity$1.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:68)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-15 04:37:46.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 04:42:46.598: I/Process(2137): Sending signal. PID: 2137 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Eclipse even shows a warning for this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array adapter has a list of `Client` and not `String`. To get the string shown in the listview, change this

```
String selectedText = (String) listview
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
```

to something like

```
String selectedText = ((Client) listview
                .getItemAtPosition(position)).toString();
```

And add the `.show()` to the toast as already mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedText,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

with below:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedText,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You forgot to `.show()` in Toast. that's it.

Comment: Yes I missed .show but program still stop when I click on an item.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `.show()`

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedText,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Yes I missed .show but program still stop when I click on an item.

Comment: @user3190360 its a crash!. post the stack trace for further help

Comment: @user3190360 `com.example.assist.Client cannot be cast to java.lang.String` what does your list containt. What is your list type.

Comment: the list contains data from database.  MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

  Button backListButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backListButton_ID);
  backListButton.setOnClickListener(this);

  final List list = db.getAllClients();

Comment: @user3190360 what is the type of the list. does the list contain strings.??.bcoz the log says that `listview
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);` returns client not string but your casting it to a string see lalto's answer and check if that helps

Comment: @user3190360 you stacktrace does tell its does not